# Sandbox: bluetoothd(112) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.server.bluetooth

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth, console

[image]

I have a MacBook pro. I can able to Turn on Bluetooth but I can't able to connect with any device. This means I can't able to see any available device on my list.

I try to confirm the issues, I go into the console and search Bluetooth and I can see this error.

`Sandbox: bluetoothd(112) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.server.bluetooth`

Please refer to below screenshot to get more ideas.

[image]